# How to debug android quickly?

Tags: android

When I modify some code, I need to operate the virtual machine again. It is cost too much time.

Who knows some good method to debug the code quickly?

Comment: This is a very vague question... Please be more specific.

Comment: Are you closing the AVD after every publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First debug to project . Not close it and edit your code then run or debug . you will see to debug on same open emulator and will save a bit time . 
other ways :-  You can use your Android phone for quick debug . follow it http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

this step for window 7.

```
1.Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
2.Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select Manage.
3.Select Devices in the left pane.
4.Locate and expand Other device in the right pane.
5.Right-click the device name (such as Nexus S) and select Update Driver Software. This will     launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
6.Select Browse my computer for driver software and click Next.
7.Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in <sdk>\extras\google\usb_driver\.)
8.Click Next to install the driver.
```

your driver will be automatically install .

Now go to setting of your android device and check on usb-debug mode. it should be enable .

then run your android project and either it will be automatically run on your device or give you chose . it is fastest method to debug .

Answer (score 0):

Use Debug Tool provided in the eclipse and add breakpoint and you can move where ever you want quickly...